# Tools for monitoring users on L2TP VPN

Tags: monitoring, vpn, ipsec, network-monitoring, l2tp

I'm looking for some help and advice in terms of monitoring network connections to a L2TP / Ipse VPN platform Ubuntu 14.04.

My basic requirement is to get visibility of:

1) Who's logged in (over time).
2) How much data they have consumed.

A nice to have would be some configurable variables to show activity over a period of time (day, week, month).

Previously, I've been using PPTPD, and have used a great little script which is simple, but does the job. https://github.com/boukeversteegh/pptpd-monitor

I'm struggling to find anything for L2TP which has the same functionality. The only thing that comes close that I've found is 'bandwidthd', however, the available docs are pretty thin, and I'm struggling to get it configured and working.

Has anyone else managed to solve this problem in the past ?